# How to get a reference to resourcegroup members with CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-resource-group

**tldr;**

Need to import a security group and and a subnet given either a couple tags OR a known resource group.

---

For a SecurityGroup and a Subnet I've created a `resourcegroup` given this [terraform module](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/resourcegroups_group) definition:

```
resource "aws_resourcegroups_group" "private_networking" {
  name = "us-blog-private-networking"

  resource_query {
    query = <<JSON
{
  "ResourceTypeFilters": [
    "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
  ],
  "TagFilters": [
    {
      "Key": "Property",
      "Values": ["us-blog-production"]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Private",
      "Values": [true]
    }
  ]
}
JSON
  }
}
```

The fact that neither SecurityGroup or Subnet would get `fromXXAttributes` methods allowing tagging made me create a resource group.

Then I'm trying to find a way to fetch this resources and get a reference. I'd expect a L2 construct API for resourcegroups but only L1 is available.

All I got is `CfnGroup` which wouldn't have an static method to fetch the group.

I'd like to avoid having to harcode networking elements ids or going redundant creating SSM parameters with such.

What's the most appropriate approach?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you want to achieve? You want to apply tags to existing resources? CDK cannot do that natively, as imported resources cannot be modified.

Comment: @gshpychka I want to import a security group and and a subnet given either a couple tags OR a known resource group

Comment: That's not available in CDK, you can only reference a subnet or a SG by ID. You can also use API calls to look up an SG by name.

Comment: Can you offer an example for API calls with CDK?

Comment: I was referring to `SecurityGroup.fromLookupByName`, which does an API call and caches the result.

Comment: Oh right. 

So long story short this is either create a custom ... CF stack which makes it more complex OR create SSM parameters with the ids and then it'd be easy to get the ids and use lookup methods

Comment: Right but parameters can be more agnostic and descriptive.